# Python for loop in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I happen to come across the term:

`np.array([[0. for _ in range(20)] for _ in range(50)])`

It gives me all 0.0 for a matrix of 20 x 50.

However, I don't like this syntax. I am wondering if there alternative way of doing this? I want 0 to be 0.0 (as float).

Thanks

Comment: Try `[[0.0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(5)]]`.  That's basic Python list comprehension.  Don't be thrown by the use of `_`.  Next try `[[(i,j) for i in range(3)] for j in range(5)]]`.  The array part is just like `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.zeros((20, 50), dtype=np.float32)  # or any other type; default: np.float64
```

[Link to the Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

Remark: no experienced numpy-user will use the approach in your example!

Comment: I won't understand the `for _ in` notation

Comment: But that was not the question right? You did ask for an alternative and i proposed the most natural. To answer your other question: the ```_``` is nothing special. Many people use that to mark a variable which will nevber be used. You can call it ```x``` too without changing anything! The rest is basic python-stuff (iteration syntax).

Comment: @wrek You can find info about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/1394393. #3 in the accepted answer is what it's being used for here.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=np.zeros([5,8])
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> type(a[1][1])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
>>>
```

You can see from the code that the default format is float64.